# How to Read multiple Root Elements in Complex xml file using spring batch

Tags: xml, spring, spring-batch

I am current reading a large xml .I am having an xml which will have multiple clients and each client will have consumers(consumers count can be huge).Each consumer will have consumer details.

Below is the sample xml file

```
 <root>
  <fileId>123456</fileId>
  <fileDate>2008-09-29</fileDate>
  <fileTime>01:18:33</fileTime>
  <sourceSystemId>POST</sourceSystemId>
    <clients>
<!--1 or more repetitions:-->
      <client id="1">
        <consumers>
           <consumer>
            <acctNo>123456789</acctNo>
            <preferences>
                <preference>    
                </preference>
            </preferences>
            <points>
                <point1>
                    <val>123456789</val>
                </point1>
                <point2>
                    <val>123456789</val>
                </point2>

            </points>
          </consumer>
            !-- I can have 1 million consumers for client 1-->
      </consumers>

     </client>

     <client id="2">
       <consumers>
         <consumer>
            <acctNo>0997773273</acctNo>
            <preferences>
                <preference>    
                </preference>
            </preferences>
            <points>
                <point1>
                    <val>0997773273</val>
                </point1>
                <point2>
                    <val>0997773273</val>
                </point2>

            </points>
         </consumer>
            !-- I can have 1 million consumers for client 2-->
      </consumers>

  </client>
  </clients>      
  </root>
```

I can read the xml by specifing client as rootTag and i will be all the information but all the consumer will be loaded to memory which will cause memory issues.

if i specify rootTag as consumer then reader will read consumers based on the chunkside but i will not get the information which i need.

Please suggest to how to deal the above scenario.

Appreciate your help on this.

Thanks,

Comment: Any help on this please

Comment: Need quick help on this. Can any one help me this. Need to implement ASAP.